# Using babel-plugin-rewire to test private non-referenced functions

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I am using babel-plugin-rewire (https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-rewire) in main.test.js to test non-exported functions in main.js. This has been working except in the case where the function is not referenced in main.js; in this case I get the following error: TypeError: _get__(...) is not a function.

Only after I add a reference to the function in main.js I am able to access it in the test file (it works even if I don't actually call the function). However I do not want to make any changes to main.js. Is this the expected behavior of babel-plugin-rewire, and is there a workaround for this?

```
//main.js
function test123() {
    return true;
}
test123; //Cannot access function in test file unless I add this reference!

//main.test.js
const test123 = require('./main').__get__('test123');

test('test123', () => {
  expect(test123()).toEqual(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test non-exported functions in main.js, but the non-exported functions need to be used in at least one exported function in the same file.

In your case, this will work without a reference.

```
//main.js
export default function foo() {
   test123();
}
function test123() {
    return true;
}
```